# iframe in map infowindow does not fit on first load

Tags: javascript, google-maps

- small google map infowindow with iframe inside
- iframe does not fit inside infowindow on first click on marker (right side cut off)
- http://tinypic.com/r/359ikpk/8
- second click on marker fixes problem
- JSfiddle sample with problem below, but first
- you need to avoid google maps caching (cached map fixes problem)
- open in incognito/private tab

http://jsfiddle.net/armandsp/kdH9C

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'Below is iframe border<br /><iframe src="http://www.lielvarde.lv/tmp" style="width:300px; height:300px; border:3px solid red;"></iframe>'
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround

- put everything in div that is a bit bigger than content in infowindow
- http://jsfiddle.net/armandsp/u8nbzoop/

I`m guessing the infowindow has trouble measuring iframes because when the infowindow is created the iframe has no content. Then iframe loads and its scrollbars throw off somehow measuring.

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div style="width:300px; height:300px;">Title lorem ipsum<br /><iframe src="http://www.lielvarde.lv/tmp" style="width:300px; height:270px; border:9px;"></iframe></div>'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add !important; after the height and width properties on #map and be sure to set #map width: 100%;

http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/google-maps-iframe-has-height-and-width-overwritten-with-inline-styles/

Comment: There is no problem with map canvas.

iframe in infowindow does not fit - border is cut off.

Screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/359ikpk/8